# Really easy python standoff

Tags: python

I feel really dumb not to be able to solve something like this, but I'm point blank. I need to come up with a short and elegant way to do this, and for some reason I just can't!

The concept is very simple

I have a list with `[4,3,5,2,1]` and I have five individuals `A, B, C, D, E`

`A=4 B=3 C=5 D=2 E=1`

Now, I need to arrange them in ascending order based on their numbers so they become

`['E', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C']`

I seriously don't get why I can't figure this one out D:

Comment: Will the numbers always be consecutive and in the right range?

Comment: What data structure are you using to store the individuals? In your example it looks you're using variable names (`A=4`), but then you're showing strings (`['E', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C']`). Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
order  =  [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
people = "ABCDE"

result = [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(order, people))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a dictionary associating the numbers to each "individual":

```
>>> a = [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
>>> b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>> d = dict(zip(b, a))
>>> d
{'A': 4, 'C': 5, 'B': 3, 'E': 1, 'D': 2}
```

Using this dictionary, you can easily sort the keys by value:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get)
['E', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to combine the two lists into a list of tuples `[(A,1),(B,3),...,(E,5)]` and then use sort with a custom `cmp` method to compare the numbers, and then use `map` to pull the letters back out.